# Linux Mint freezes while downloading eclipse

Tags: gnome, osx, linux-mint, eclipse, parallels

I installed linux mint on parallels on my mac computer. It seemed to work fine and then, while downloading eclipse from Software Manager the entire system froze when it got to 40%. I've tried restrating the VM and the computer. It freezes at exactly 40%.

Comment: The entire system, meaning the guest or the host? (Either way, it's weird.) Do you have a web proxy? Have you experienced freezes for other reasons? Is there anything in the kernel logs (either on the host or in the guest — on Mint, look in `/var/logs/kern.log` for entries dating from about the time of the freeze).

Comment: Entire system meaning linux mint. I don't have a web proxy. I haven't experience any freezes for other reasons at all, just when I try to download eclipse and it reaches 40%.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is just with that one package you could download a newer version directly from Oracle. The version in the Mint repository is couple versions back.